# how can i control modules in package to import in python?

Tags: python

Consider an example,

I have a package having list of modules:

```
 /mypackage/
   __init__.py
   mod1.py
   mod2.py
   mod3.py
```

`prog1.py`: I would like to allow only `mod2` here
`prog2`: allow `mod1,2`

If I write,

```
prog1.py
import mypackage
# only mod2 should import

prog2.py
import mypackage
# only mod1,mod3 should import
```

How can I restrict at package or module level?

Comment: this is the one of main question In many python based interviews..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that packages should control who and how can import them, basically packages should not know about their importers. However if you for some reason still thing this is a good idea, you can get a main filename by:

```
import __main__
main_file = __main__.__file__
```

And then modify your

```
__all__
```

attribute of module based on a main file name.

Comment: 1. can we get main script name if we write above code in module?         2. can we write the above code in __init__.py file or in the module?

Answer (score 3):

```
from mypackage import mod2
```

or

```
from mypackage import mod1, mod3
```

Comment: Hi Danie, Thanks for response..Here in the above code we are limiting modules to import in our importer script but I wanted to restrict modules to import from package. I mean package level restriction.